# requirements.txt file for my package missing from PyPI install and tarball

Tags: python, git, github, pip, pypi

I followed the instructions from http://peterdowns.com/posts/first-time-with-pypi.html in order to add my github hosted python package to PyPI. However when I try to pip install it and it runs my setup.py I get that the requirements.txt file is missing. When I manually download the tarball file from `https://github.com/<username>/<mypackage>/archive/0.1.tar.gz` I find that all the files are there. However when I click the download link on the PyPI page for my package it downloads a .tar.gz archive which only contains the python files, the config file and a PKG-INFO file it appears to have created.

The other files are all gone, why is this and how might I fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`setuptools` by default chooses which files to include automatically based on your modules added -- by default this generally just means your python files and `__init__.py` files.

To specify other files that need to be included in your source distribution, you can add a `MANIFEST.in` file to graft additional files into your source distribution.

An example one which includes requirements.txt:

```
include requirements.txt
```

These can be come [sufficiently more complicated](https://github.com/asottile/dockerfile/blob/747820ba2443456e20cec45b0d95474193577c88/MANIFEST.in)

To find all the things that MANIFEST.in supports, you can read its documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/sourcedist.html#the-manifest-in-template).

Comment: This appears to work in that the files are included in the .tar.gz archive that I can download from PyPI and when I pip install the module it appears to download the files (as it installs correctly and checks all the requirements are there). However when I attempt to run my package it looks in the install directory for a file (`/Users/<username>/anaconda/envs/testenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/datahandling/VERSION`) in my particular case and cannot find the file. When I go into this directory myself the files in my manifest, that should be in this sub-directory, are not there.

Comment: They appear to be downloaded correctly initially at least, for the package to install and find the requirements. But after installation they are not in the directory that houses the package.

Comment: My MANIFEST.in file looks like so:

```include requirements.txt
include <packagename>/VERSION
include LICENSE```

The VERSION file is in the .tar.gz and must be downloaded for the installation to occur correctly without errors, so it is being downloaded when the package is pip installed. But it is not ultimately copied to the install location.

Comment: If you want it to be copied to the installed location, you'll want to look at [package_data=](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#including-data-files) -- that said, I think you're over-complicating your setup.py -- requirements specified through `install_requires` should work just fine.  As for version, if you just specify the string in setup.py, you can access it at runtime by [`pkg_resources.get_distribution('pkgname').version`](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#getting-or-creating-distributions)

Comment: I may be slightly over complicating matters at the moment but I intend to publish a package soon which requires files in other programming languages in the install directory so I wanted to solve it for an easier problem first.

Comment: `include_package_data=True` worked to copy my MANIFEST.in files to the install directory, thanks!